# Writing a C# asp.net MVC 4 app, want it to open a SSO to GoogleSuite Edu, can't find examples or docs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, google-docs

I'm writing a C# asp.net MVC 4 app,

I want it to open a window that SSO to GoogleSuite Edu, (We have O365 set up, looking at moving to Google)

(Ie Login to  our app, click link, goto Google Docs, already logged in)

can't find examples or docs.

I can find lots of stuff about setting up the Google side, or about this or that api, but nothing with any detail about creating an app to do it.

From what I've read the best approach seems to be setting up Google to use our app as a 3rd party authenticator via ADFS as an IdP service, login thru Google, then just add a link to Google docs I our app.

Is this  the best approach, are they an y examples or tutorials I can look at?

I found the c# quickstart for Google+ login, but it doesn't work due to bad JS code.

just setting up google suite and replicating users and Pwds seems pretty straight forward, it's the SSO from our app that most concerns me.

Comment: Found this, but it doesn't work. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

Comment: Got it working by doing the ssl stuff manually.

Comment: I found it useful to get this one up and running first, before the one above, just to get my feet wet
https://developers.google.com/+/web/samples/csharp

After I got both of these working I turned SSO on in the admin console for my project and SSO "just worked'.